# vertical align text in a label with set number of rows

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I am have been a few problems with the above issue. I have a label in a table view (X-300, Y-26, width-192 and height-42) which will contain random and unknown strings of varying lengths. The max number of rows should be 2. The text should always be at the top of the label.

I have a working solution (below) but it just seems so dirty - there must be a cleaner way to do something that seems so simple:

```
UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

// First set cell lines back to 0 and reset height and width of the label - otherwise it works until you scroll down as cells are reused.
cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0; 
cellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cellLabel.frame.origin.x, cellLabel.frame.origin.y, 192, 42);

// Set the text and call size to fit
[cellLabel setText:[[products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];
[cellLabel sizeToFit];

// Set label back to 2 lines.
cellLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

// This 'if' solves a weird the problem when the text is so long the label ends "..." - and the label is slightly higher.
if (cellLabel.frame.size.height > 42) {
    cellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cellLabel.frame.origin.x, cellLabel.frame.origin.y, 192, 42);
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with xcode and instead is about UILabel, so I'm removing the Xcode tag and adding a UILabel tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use, a category on UILabel. I'm setting the max height of the label + the tail truncation. This is a modified version of the sizeToFitFixedWidth: method I found on another SO post.. maybe you can use something like this to accomodate your max number of lines ?

```
@implementation UILabel (customSizeToFit)

- (void)sizeToFitFixedWidth:(CGFloat)fixedWidth andMaxHeight:(CGFloat)maxHeight;
{
    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, fixedWidth, 0);
    self.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    self.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self sizeToFit];

    if (maxHeight != 0.0f && self.frame.size.height > maxHeight) {
        self.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, fixedWidth, maxHeight);
    }    
}

@end
```